# When I attempt to add styles to a HTML anchor tag I'm out putting with PHP the links stop working

Tags: php, css

The following code works and when echoed displays appropriate user names  on the webpage,

```
$loginLink = '<a href="user.php?u='.$log_username.'">'.$log_username.'</a><a href="logout.php">Log Out</a>';
```

Fine and dandy, the html output is displayed, however when I add styles to the anchor tag the styles work but the links stop working, even when I create a surrounding div and add styles to that the code stops working.

How I added the styles originally, where the links stop working

```
$loginLink = '<a class="username_button" href="user.php?u='.$log_username.'">'.$log_username.'</a><a class="logout_button" href="logout.php">Log Out</a>';
```

The rendered HTML in the source code shows as follows,

```
        <p><a class="username_button" href="user.php?u=NoelVock">NoelVock</a><a class="logout_button" href="logout.php">Log Out</a></p>
```

Am I missing something small as usual?

Any comments would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you put the rendered HTML into your question?

Comment: Something's wrong probably. We can't tell however if you don't elaborate on the interfering changes.

Comment: show us how do you add styles

Comment: To help you one would need to see the code that's not working instead of the working parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$loginLink = '<a href="user.php?u='.$log_username.'" style="color:red; background:gray;">'.$log_username.'</a><a href="logout.php">Log Out</a>';
```

I think theirs nothing wrong with this example